# What kind of tree am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am a tree on highest mountain.
>   I am many, don't try countin'.
>   I grow skinny. I grow fat.
>   Chop me down and I'll grow back.
>
> Many mountains are my home.
>   You don't plant me. I just grow.
>   Sometimes I just go away.
>   Though people wish that I would stay.

**What kind of tree am I?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are:

> HAIR (as on the head)

I am a tree on highest mountain.

> Something that grows in a high place. The top of our head is as high as we get in a way.

I am many, don't try countin'.

> One has numerous hairs, normally too many count.

I grow skinny. I grow fat.

> Presumably about the thickness variations in people's hair.

Chop me down and I'll grow back.

> Hair keeps growing regardless of being cut to nothingness (as in a shaved head)

Many mountains are my home.

> The head has bumps.

You don't plant me. I just grow.

> One does not plant hair seeds. Hair grows naturally without seeds.

Sometimes I just go away.
Though people wish that I would stay.

> This refers to people who are bald. They normally seem to dislike the condition.

Comment: 2 minutes!? I seriously overestimated my riddle making skills.

Comment: It's quite OK really - nice and classical

Comment: @LCIII you should try when d'alar'cop is sleeping :)

Comment: A hair tree?  Gross?

Comment: @skv - he never sleeps :-p

Comment: I had to plant my hair with hair seeds. :P

Answer (score 3):

I think "Hope"(dream) would be a beautiful solution, too!

I am a tree on highest mountain.

> Something far away we are trying to reach.

I am many, don't try countin'.

> There are many people hoping for something and maybe everyone has many "trees" he is looking at. But there is no point counting them.

I grow skinny. I grow fat.

> Hope can have all different shapes and it can change over time. You sometimes change your mind and thus change hope to some point.

Chop me down and I'll grow back.

> Reminds me of someone trying to destroy your dreams but hope is returning. They say 'hope' is what dies last.

Many mountains are my home.

> Many people can have the same dream or hope for something.

You don't plant me. I just grow.

> You cannot control what you want. Sometimes you desire forbidden things.

Sometimes I just go away. Though people wish that I would stay.

> Sometimes an opportunity vanishes and as a result, hope dies eventually even though you still want to pursue it.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit this answer to explain how you reached this conclusion given the information in the question?

Comment: @Emrakul the tryhard :') Ok, I will

Comment: +1 This answer is no less applicable than the "correct" answer!