# My French killer ... what does this mean?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

What is the meaning of the following sentence?

> My French killer married the hammerer cooked in oil, seated beneath a daily beacon.

(The answer will be obvious once you see it!)

Comment: If you remove letters from "hammerer" and "beacon", you get "ham" and "bacon"...?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It simply lists:

> The days of the week

Reasoning:

> *My French* => mon (french for "my")
>  *killer* => tue (french for "kills")
>  *married* => wed
>  *the hammerer* => thur (play on Thor)
>  *cooked in oil* => fri (from fry)
>  *seated beneath* => sat
>  *a daily beacon* => sun

Comment: "Tue" is "kills" in French.

Comment: @xnor - Yeah, just realised that one myself... well, I had, killer => tueror, but yours is better, so I'm shamelessly stealing it. Thanks. :)

Comment: Well done! :-) Seems I managed to find the right balance of difficulty with this one...

Comment: @randal'thor - yeah, balance is really hard... I feel like my [last one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11664/bathed-in-violence-say-my-name) must have been a touch too easy (or d'alar'cop is just too good). But this was definitely a good one. Well done. :)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think your last riddle was too easy: it's very hard to know where to start, but once you see the solution, it's obvious that everything fits and that it's right. Which is exactly how a riddle should be :-) And yes, d'alar'cop is extremely good. He used to be PSE's top user and have people make comments like [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4270/what-kind-of-tree-am-i#comment12230_4271) about him! If he'd been active on the site since December, he'd probably have 20k rep by now.

Comment: @randal'thor - Ha! Well that does make me feel better. And, I guess therein lies the challenge of balance... You're working against an imbalanced audience. :P

Answer (score 14):

I guess:

> It's a description of a breakfast: a bloody mary (French killer + 'married'), bangers and mash (to hammer on something is to bang on it, not totally sure about the cooked in oil part but cooking something in oil is frying it), and a sunny-side up egg ('daily beacon' sounds like the sun to me).